# How to make same width in responsive blocks-items, even if the last ones have free space

Tags: html, css

I want to make items in list all same size and responsive. I regulate min-width, max-width and flex-grow: 1 if they have free space. But last items, if you see my codepen, if they have free space, they will have all bigger size then the others, I don't want this 
behavior. How to fix this without mediaqueries, becouse the size of container will be dynamically undefined, and the count of items are undefined too.

```
.item {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 250px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/magistr19/pen/MWgPxBW?editors=1100

UPD: Need good browser support (CSS grids not fit)

Comment: remove  flex-grow: 1; from item class.

Comment: Try [`css grids`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: now they have all min size, and don't take free space

Comment: css grids is nice solution, but I need support of old browsers (

Comment: your max-width is 250px that's why after getting space it's taking 250px for last two.

Comment: Not sure how old browser you support but you may consider that try using `table`

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I know, but if I don't set max-width, they will be oversized

Comment: @Chaska how to make table with items break on new line, if they have no space more when resizing window

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

> How to make same width in responsive blocks-items, even if the last ones have free space

CSS-Grid is good solution for you problem

**Result**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #008000;
}

.item {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Css grid is great solution, but I am sorry, I need support of old browsers like IE 10,11 and Iphones 5... =(